# Getting Data from a Simple XML

Tags: xml, haskell, arrows, hxt

I am trying to extract some data from an XML input with 6 lines, using HXT. I want to keep HXT, too, because of the Curl integration and because I have other XML files with thousands of lines, later.

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<find>
    <set_number>228461</set_number>
    <no_records>000000008</no_records>
    <no_entries>000000008</no_entries>
</find>
```

And I've been trying to get together how to parse that. Unfortunately, the Wiki page of HXT has not been a big help (or I just did overlook stuff).

```
data FindResult = FindResult {
        resultSetNumber :: String,
        resultNoRecords :: Int,
        resultNoEntries :: Int
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

resultParser :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree FindResult
resultParser = hasName "find" >>> getChildren >>> proc x -> do
    setNumber <- isElem >>> hasName "set_number" >>> getChildren >>> getText -< x
    noRecords <- isElem >>> hasName "no_records" >>> getChildren >>> getText -< x
    noEntries <- isElem >>> hasName "no_entries" >>> getChildren >>> getText -< x
    returnA -< FindResult setNumber (read noRecords) (read noEntries)

find str = return . head =<< (runX $ readDocument [withValidate no, withCurl []] query >>> resultParser)
    where query = "http://" ++ server ++ "/find?request=" ++ str
```

What I always get is

```
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

so, I guess, the parsing must go horribly wrong, since I checked and correctly get the XML from the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works for me (modelled after [this example](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HXT/Practical/Simple1)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}

module Main
       where

import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import System.Environment

data FindResult = FindResult {
        resultSetNumber :: String,
        resultNoRecords :: Int,
        resultNoEntries :: Int
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

resultParser :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree FindResult
resultParser =
  deep (isElem >>> hasName "find") >>> proc x -> do
    setNumber <- getText <<< getChildren <<< deep (hasName "set_number") -< x
    noRecords <- getText <<< getChildren <<< deep (hasName "no_records") -< x
    noEntries <- getText <<< getChildren <<< deep (hasName "no_entries") -< x
    returnA -< FindResult setNumber (read noRecords) (read noEntries)

main :: IO ()
main = do [src] <- getArgs
          res <- runX $ ( readDocument [withValidate no] src >>> resultParser)
          print . head $ res
```

Testing:

```
$ dist/build/test/test INPUT
FindResult {resultSetNumber = "228461", resultNoRecords = 8, resultNoEntries = 8}
```